# React native, set height for flatlist container according to space contain by item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to set height of flatlist container equal to height equal to space taken by it's item like in the image below

[image]

but I'm getting the same result

[image]

2nd item container took same space as 1st item container can someone tell me how to fix that? below is my code

```
<FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item._id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.container}
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate(strings.VIEW_QUOTE, {
            image: item.image_url,
            text: item.description,
          })
        }
      >
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: item.image_url,
          }}
          style={{
            height: moderateScaleVertical(153),
            resizeMode: "stretch",
          }}
        />
        <Text style={styles.text}>{item.description}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }}
        numColumns={2}
        style={{
          marginHorizontal: moderateScale(12),
        }}
      />
....
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    overflow: "hidden",
    marginHorizontal: moderateScaleVertical(4),
    marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(20),
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: colors.blackOpacity15,
    borderRadius: 5,
    flex: 1,
  },
  text: {
    ...commonStyles.fontSize15,
    fontFamily: fontFamily.medium,
    marginHorizontal: moderateScale(6),
  },
});
```

Comment: ```flex: 1``` in container styles might be the reason for it, try removing it.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is known as masonry layout in web development. I used a library for the same effect called "react-native-masonry-layout". Maybe it might help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can put an onLayout function to FlatList.

```
const [flatListHeight, setFlatListHeight] = useState(0);

const onLayout = (e) => {
   setFlatListHeight(e.nativeEvent.layout.height);
}

return (
  <FlatList onLayout={onLayout} />
);
```